# Ideal Battery in Circuit

Tags: batteries, kirchhoffs-laws, ideal

Does Kirchoff's voltage law hold when we connect a single battery to a circuit that has no other components.

If it does hold, kindly let me know how.

If it doesn't, how do we reconcile with that?

Comment: I don't understand your question. How can you connect a battery to a circuit which has no other components - how can there be a circuit when there are no components? Maybe draw a schematic to make it clear what you are asking about.

Comment: I guess my question boils down to: how do we go on to explain what happens when we connect the positive and negative terminals of an ideal battery with a resistance-less wire.

Comment: You will disappear into the singularity that you create. Don't do that!

Comment: Do this with a candidate ideal battery - say a 1000 Ah 48V LiIon solar battery, and a candidate ideal wire -  say a 25mm diameter copper cable and it will be a race to see whether the cable, the battery or you die first. In the ideal case Kirchoff observes V/0 = very very very very ... large.  Mathematicians are needed to explain divide by zero in ideal situations. Undertakers and/or scrap metal buyers in real world ones.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The current may be very large, as you say, but the potential drop across the wire would still be 0 as R is exactly zero. Hence, I do not see how KVL is valid in this case

Comment: @AkaiShuichi You need to read what I and others have said (more) carefully. In your cannot-exist ideal case you have made non ideal assumptions which are not valid. As the ideal case deviates from reality so the answers are invalid in practice. You have arbitrarily decided that the voltage across an ideal wire MUST be zero BUT have failed to equally validly decide that the voltage across an ideal V volt battery is V volts - even when shorted with 0 Ohms. | So, as noted by I and others I = V/R = V/0 = "infinite". Kirchoff gets his V volts, the wire gets its infinite amps and we all die :-).

Comment: @RussellMcMahon I was slow to comprehend. I see it now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a thought experiment, or a real world one if you have a death wish, take a candidate almost-ideal battery - say a 1000 Ah 48V LiIon solar battery, and a candidate ideal wire -  say a 25mm diameter copper cable  - and it will be a race to see whether the cable, the battery or you die first.

In the ideal case Kirchoff observes V/0 = very very very very ... large.
Mathematicians are needed to explain divide by zero in ideal situations.
Undertakers and/or scrap metal buyers in real world ones.

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do is a circuit which is not defined.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCskLks.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you try to apply Kirchhoffs law to this circuit what will you get? The sum of the voltages is 1 V, there is no component where the 1 V will drop. So this circuit is not suited to be analyzed by this.

If you try to calculate the current with Ohms law, you end up dividing by zero. Which is not defined.

In the real world, you always encounter some non-ideal components. So even if you connect a superconductor directly to battery there will be a defined behavior because the battery has an internal resistance for example.

Answer (score 0):

According KVL, the voltage across the battery will be same as voltage across the wire you connect.

The current will be very high and you may hurt yourself. The wire might melt or in worst case the battery might explode.

Please assume that the battery will have some finite internal resistance and also the wire has some non zero resistance. Then you can draw the circuit and verify it yourself.

If you connect a ideal battery to a ideal wire then KVL won't still fail. The current will be infinite.

Comment: The potential drop across the wire would be infinite*0 (resistance is 0 ohms) which is still 0. How, then, is KVL still valid?

Comment: @AkaiShuichi https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/28940/why-is-infty-cdot-0-not-clearly-equal-to-0